# What is the naming convention to migrate a Phaser 2/CE project to Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have worked on [some Phaser projects](https://github.com/albator2018) when it was called Phaser, and want to migrate some of them to Phaser 3

As the main project is called phaser and not Phaser 3 and that my projects are named phaser-something but contains Phaser CE build, is it better to migrate them to phaser3-something or I just have to call them phaser-ce-something first then create a Phaser 3 repo specifically for the new version of Phaser?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a pretty large, and potentially very opinion-based, question, as it sort of depends on your own style.

Generally speaking, if you're not going to have multiple versions of the same game, that differ in the version of Phaser used (and the necessary code changes, which there would be a lot), then there shouldn't really be any reason to end up with two repos for your code. Two repos, like what Phaser has done for [version 2 CE](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce) and [version 3](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser), is generally if you need to continue to support both versions of Phaser.

A few reasons you might want to do this:

1. Your project includes demos/starter templates that you want to share that are specific to Phaser releases. Biased example is [my starter templates repo for Phaser](https://github.com/JamesSkemp/phaser-starter-templates). Code that ties to a tutorial would be another case.
2. You've created a plugin that you want Phaser 2 CE and Phaser 3 users to be able to use. Code for each would be different, and specific to the version of Phaser being used.

If you're just looking to upgrade your projects from Phaser 2 CE to Phaser 3 you can either:

1. Create a new branch in your existing repo to work in, and then merge into master once done.
2. Create a new repo to work in and then mark the old one as deprecated, or just delete it, once done.

This really just depends upon what you want to do, and whether you want the old code/project. So:

> As the main project is called phaser and not phaser 3 and that my projects are named phaser-something but contains phaser ce build [...]

Do whatever makes sense to you. Again, unless you're planning on keeping around both projects and continuing to support them, it doesn't matter.

> is it better to migrate them to phaser3-something or I just have to call them phaser-ce-something first then create a phaser 3 repo specifically for the new version of phaser ?

If you do want to keep both your projects around, then this makes sense. But, I might suggest calling it Phaser 2 CE, and not just Phaser CE; it's possible that there might be a Phaser 3 CE in a few years.

Might not matter here, but keep in mind that if anyone does have a local clone, or there's other existing links, they will be broken when you rename a repo.

Having worked with Phaser for a number of years, 2/2 CE/3, my recommendation would be to keep your repo's name as-is and make a branch. I personally find it easier to start with a new files specific to Phaser 3 and then port over code, instead of upgrading in-place. This allows you to immediately get a working (albeit empty) Phaser 3 game up and running, and then add to it to make it complete.

The alternative would be to start updating references to Phaser 3 and fix what breaks, which is also fine, but enough of the framework changed that you'd probably have to touch every significant line of code.

Hope that helps.